# I want to export one specific column from my DataGrid to Excel

Tags: c#, excel, datagridview

here is my code. I want to export Column6 and it rows to an Excel sheet. How can i do it?

```
        Excel.Application excel = new Excel.Application();
        excel.Visible = true;
        object Missing = Type.Missing;
        Workbook workbook = excel.Workbooks.Add(Missing);
        Worksheet worksheet = (Worksheet)workbook.Sheets[1];
        for (int i = 5; i < dataGridView6.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            worksheet.Cells[1, 1] = dataGridView6.Columns[i].HeaderText;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView6.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {   
            for (int j = 5; j < dataGridView6.Columns.Count - 1; j++)
            {
                worksheet.Cells[1, 1] = dataGridView6.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
            }
        }


    }
```

Comment: "...how can  i do it..." - this information is not really helpful. It does not say what exactly did not work, i.e. did you get any error messages anywhere, did you try to debug the issue to make sure that it actually does the intended thing.

Comment: worksheet.Cells[1, 1] = dataGridView6.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString(); Is it something wrong at this line where you keep on replace row data to single cell?